# DAX support required: Summarizing value while ignoring a visual filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following simplified Table

| Company | Project | Period | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 13 | 10 | 20 |
| A | A | 13 | 10 | 20 |
| A | B | 13 |  | 20 |
| A | B | 13 |  | 20 |
| A | C | 13 | 10 | 20 |
| A | C | 13 | 20 | 20 |
| A | D | 13 |  | 20 |
| A | D | 13 |  | 10 |

I want to create a measure that returns me a fixed value by dividing the sum of non blank value1 and the sum of non blank value2 whereas the sum of these values is grouped by Company and Period.

Here is what I have created to "achieve" the above desired result

```sql
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            'Table',
            'Table'[Value1] <> BLANK ()        
),
       'Table'[Company],
        'Table'[Period],
        "Result",
            VAR SumValue1=
                SUM ( 'Table'[Value1] )
            VAR SumValue2 =
                SUM ( 'Table'[Value2] )
            RETURN
                SumValue1/ SumValue2
    ),
    [Result]
)
```

And I get the following as a result if I use this measure, it seems that measure is calculating row by row

```
| Company | Project | Period | Value1 | Value2 | Result |
|---------|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| A       | A       | 13     | 10     | 20     | 0,5    |
| A       | A       | 13     | 10     | 20     | 0,5    |
| A       | B       | 13     |        | 20     | 0      |
| A       | B       | 13     |        | 20     | 0      |
| A       | C       | 13     | 10     | 20     | 0,5    |
| A       | C       | 13     | 20     | 20     | 1      |
| A       | D       | 13     |        | 20     | 0      |
| A       | D       | 13     |        | 10     | 0      |
| Total   |         |        |        |        | 0,3333 |

Sum(Value1) = 50

Sum(Value2) = 150

Result = 50/150= 0,333333
```

Whereas I expected the fixed value based on the sum of non blank value1 and sum of non blank value2 should be applied

```
| Company | Project | Period | Value1 | Value2 | Result |
|---------|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| A       | A       | 13     | 10     | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | A       | 13     | 10     | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | B       | 13     |        | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | B       | 13     |        | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | C       | 13     | 10     | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | C       | 13     | 20     | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | D       | 13     |        | 20     | 0,3333 |
| A       | D       | 13     |        | 10     | 0,3333 |
| Total   |         |        |        |        | 0,3333 |
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Kind regards,
Rookie12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ALLEXCEPT function in your DAX measure to remove all filters except filters on the Company and Period columns :

```
MyMeasure = 
VAR TotalValue1 = 

    CALCULATE(
        SUM('MyDataset'[Value1]),
        ALLEXCEPT('MyDataset', 'MyDataset'[Company], 'MyDataset'[Period]),
        NOT(ISBLANK('MyDataset'[Value1]))
    )

VAR TotalValue2 = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('MyDataset'[Value2]),
        ALLEXCEPT('MyDataset', 'MyDataset'[Company], 'MyDataset'[Period])
    )

RETURN
    IF(TotalValue2 <> 0, TotalValue1 / TotalValue2, BLANK())
```

[image]